# Launch Click CLI Application from inside python code

Tags: python, click, python-click

I would like to integrate a python CLI written using click into a python CLI application built using another framework. Rewriting the calling application is not an option.

As part of the integration, I need to invoke the click CLI from within code passing the arguments it should consume directly. How do I do this?

For a concrete example, consider that I'd invoke this as `foobar theclickcli <args>` where `foobar` is the CLI not written in click and `theclickcli` is a subcommand that should invoke my click CLI with its arguments (`<args>`).

I see that click offers the [`click.testing.CLIRunner`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/testing/) class which allows invoking a group or command. However, the documentation notes that:

> "...[this] should really only be used for testing as they change the entire interpreter state for simplicity and are not in any way thread-safe".

Is there an "idiomatic" way of invoking a click CLI (not just a subcommand) given an `argv` argument list like in argparse?

Comment: Is there a must for you to have it integrated into the same python process? What do you want to.do with the stdandard input/output of your click CLI? Why don't you just invoke the whole application as subprocess?

Comment: Yes it must be part of the same python process (context: I'm creating a conda plugin that uses pluggy but the plugin has a CLI fully built using click)

Comment: you can invoke a Click CLI from within your code using the click.Context and click.Command.invoke() method.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new Context object manually and invoke the command using the Context.invoke() method.
example:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name', default='World', help='Who to greet')
def hello(name):
    click.echo(f'Hello, {name}!')

def invoke_click_command(args):
    ctx = click.Context(hello)
    ctx.invoke(hello, args=args)
```